# cx_Oracle gives OCI-22062 invalid input string when calling function with bool parameter

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle

I have a strange problem. When I try to call an oracle stored function using cursor.call_func method I receive an OCI-22062 exception. I'm using Python 3.2 and cx_Oracle 5.1.2. It generally looks like this:

This is the function header for package pkg_planista:

```
FUNCTION zatwierdz_plan (p_pl_id             IN dz_plany.ID%TYPE,
                         p_czy_nowy_algorytm IN BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE, 
                         p_czy_prz_grup      IN BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE
) RETURN NUMBER;
```

This is what I do:

```
print(proc_name, retType, params, keyword_params)
res = self.cursor.callfunc(proc_name, retType, params, keyword_params)
```

This print above prints:

```
pkg_planista.zatwierdz_plan <class 'int'> [83, False] {}
```

And when the callfunc is executed, the OCI-22062 error is raised: cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: OCI-22062: invalid input string [False]

How should I pass the boolean parameter to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I had to find a workaround for this problem, because I couldn't find a way to make the callfunc work as it should.

In this workaround I use one temporary table that was created for some other purpose, but it's just what I need.

I changed callfunc to execute and made it like this:

```
self.cursor.execute("""
        declare
        result number;
        begin
        result := pkg_planista.zatwierdz_plan(:pid, :alg = 1);
        INSERT INTO tmp_dz_v_planista_pracownicy values (result);
        end;
        """, {'pid': pl_id, 'alg': int(new_algorithm)})
ret = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tmp_dz_v_planista_pracownicy")
```

This way I can call the function and receive it's return value. The tmp_dz_v_planista_pracownicy table is just a temporary table with one column of type NUMBER.